# Creating a grammar for function prototypes and declaration bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I'm build a compiler for a school project. Everything works fine but I am having difficulty with defining a grammar for functions. I have to detect if there are zero or more parameters and if the function is either a prototype or definition. I keep getting shift/reduce and/or reduce/reduce errors. I have tried many variations with no avail. Here is what I have, only looking for pointers in another direction or ideas on how to fix this.

```
function   : parameters ';'   {free_ast($2); $$ = $1;}
           | parameters block {$$ = adopt1($1, $2)}
           ;

parameters : paramlist ')'   {free_ast($2); $$ = $1;}
           | '(' identdecl ')' {free_ast($3); $$ = adopt_func2($1, $2);}
           ;

paramlist  : paramlist ',' identdecl {free_ast($2);
                                      $$ = adopt1($1, $2);}
           | '(' identdecl           {$$ = adopt_func2($1, $2);}

identdecl  : basetype TOK_ARRAY TOK_IDENT {$$ = adopt2($1, $2,
                                           change_symbol(
                                           $3, TOK_DECLID));}
           | basetype TOK_IDENT           {$$ = adopt1($1,
                                           change_symbol(
                                           $2, TOK_DECLID));}
           ;

block      : stateseq '}'       {free_ast($2); $$ = $1;}
           | ';'                {free_ast($1);}
           ;
```

adopt_func2 adopts a definition so part of my problem would be where to adopt_proto. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the difference between a prototype and a declaration? What is the grammar? How does this relate to C++?

Comment: Im sorry for adding c++, i 'm using c++ to write everything else. It's late and I've been working on this for awhile. A prototype doesn't have a block statement and a definition does, just like c++. so int foo (); //proto and int foo () { ... } for definition. There is also that semicolon too.

Comment: A prototype in C++ is a declaration. A *definition* is what includes a function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the issue has nothing to do with the declaration/definition similarity. The problem is that you have a special case for a parameter list with exactly one parameter, leading to an ambiguity:

```
parameters : paramlist ')'
           | '(' identdecl ')'
           ;

paramlist  : paramlist ',' identdecl 
           | '(' identdecl
           ;
```

So `(type id)` can be reduced using either the first production for `parameters`, where `paramlist` is reduced with its second production, or it can be reduced directly using the second production for `parameters`. I can't see any obvious need for the second production for `parameters`, so I'd suggest just removing it.

However, that is (imho) a really ugly way of writing the grammar, since it hides the symmetry of the parentheses. It also does not recognize a parameter list with zero parameters. So I'd suggest:

```
parameters : '(' paramlist ')'
           | '(' ')'

paramlist  : identdecl
           | paramlist ',' identdecl
```

which I think is much clearer.

Comment: I think it's coming from some other part but when I parse a file now, I get a syntax error from my parser saying unexpected '(', expecting ')' or ','. It could be some other grammar I have but there isn't a shift/reduce or reduce/reduce problem. Although, there is a reduce/reduce issue from the semicolon in function and block.

Comment: @corn_flakes: You allow `block` to be a single `;`, which means that a definition might look exactly like a declaration. You really should fix that ambiguity. I would also recommend rewriting your `block` rule the same way as I did `parameters`, so that the `{` and `}` are in the same production. (As shown, no production includes a `{` so that's definitely not going to work.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. The continuation for block is    stateseq : stateseq statement {$$ = adopt1($1, $2);}
           | '{'                {$$ = change_symbol($1, TOK_BLOCK);}
           ;